# Escape key to Close WxPython GUI

Tags: python, wxpython

I am working on a rather simple wxpython GUI, and would like to be able to have the escape key close the window. Right now I just have a close button that executes sys.exit(0), but I'd like the escape key to do this to.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

```
import win32clipboard
import wx
from time import sleep
import sys

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,title):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="-RRESI Rounder-", pos=(0,0), size=(210,160))
        panel=Panel(self)

        icon = wx.Icon('ruler_ico.ico', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO) 
        self.SetIcon(icon) 

class Panel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        x1=10; x2=110
        y1=40; dy=25; ddy=-3
        boxlength=80

        self.button =wx.Button(self, label="GO", pos=(100,y1+dy*3))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick,self.button)
        self.button.SetDefault()

        self.button2 =wx.Button(self, label="Close", pos=(100,y1+dy*4))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose, self.button2)
        self.button.SetDefault()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.OnKeyUP)

        self.label1 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Input Number:", pos=(x1,y1+dy*1))
        self.Input = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="1.001", pos=(x2,ddy+y1+dy*1), size=(boxlength,-1))

        self.label0 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Round to closest:  1/", pos=(x1,y1+dy*0))
        self.Denominator = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="64", pos=(x2,ddy+y1+dy*0), size=(boxlength,-1))

        self.label2 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Output Number:", pos=(x1,y1+dy*2))
        self.display = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="1.0", pos=(x2,ddy+y1+dy*2), size=(boxlength,-1))
        self.display.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(232, 232, 232))

        self.label3 = wx.StaticText(self, label="          ", pos=(x2+7,y1+dy*2+20)) #Copied

        self.label4 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Type value and hit Enter", pos=(x1-5,y1-dy*1.5))
        self.label5 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Output is copied", pos=(x1-5,y1-dy*1))
        font = wx.Font(8, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        self.label4.SetFont(font)
        self.label5.SetFont(font)

    def OnKeyUP(self, event): 
        keyCode = event.GetKeyCode() 
        if keyCode == wx.WXK_ESCAPE: 
            sys.exit(0) 


    def OnClose(self, event):
        print "Closed"
        sys.exit(0)

    def OnClick(self,event):      
        print "You clicked the button!"

        def openClipboard():
            try:
                win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
            except Exception, e:
                print e
                pass

        def closeClipboard():
            try:
                win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
            except Exception, e:
                print e
                pass

        def clearClipboard():
            try:
                openClipboard()
                win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
                closeClipboard()
            except TypeError:
                pass

        def setText(txt): 
            openClipboard()
            win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
            win32clipboard.SetClipboardText(txt) 
            closeClipboard()

        Denominator = float(self.Denominator.GetValue())
        Input=float(self.Input.GetValue())
        Output=round(Input*Denominator,0)/Denominator
        self.display.SetValue(str(Output))
        setText(str(Output))
        self.label3.SetLabel("Copied")
        self.Update()#force redraw 
        sleep(.5)
        wx.Timer
        self.label3.SetLabel("                    ")


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)   # Error messages don't go to popup window
    frame = MainFrame("RRESI Rounder")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: harder than it looks apparently...

Comment: i have tried Joran Beasley's code, it works. but no fortunate at my own. i did a bit invastigate the key is `panel.SetFocus()`. it looks the event is only triggerred after `SetFocus()` to ui control

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sorta works ... albiet with some issues

[edit]ok EVT_CHAR_HOOK works much better than EVT_KEY_UP

```
import wx

class Test(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, title='Event Test',
size=(200, 200))

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        panel.SetFocus()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.OnKeyUP)

    def OnKeyUP(self, event):
        print "KEY UP!"
        keyCode = event.GetKeyCode()
        if keyCode == wx.WXK_ESCAPE:
            self.Close()
        event.Skip() 


class App(wx.App):
    """Application class."""

    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = Test()
        self.frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.SetFocus()
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Alright, thanks! I tried that example with EVT_KEY_UP and it didn't do anything, I'll try it with the EVT_CHAR_HOOK

Comment: Maybe the `event.Skip()` should be in an `else:` clause. That would ensure that no default handling of Esc key also happens.

Comment: meh it should be fine to just skip in general .. in the worst case an exception is raised and it crashes... but its closed all the same

Answer (score 0):

Probably an easier way is to set the frame up as a dialogue with a cancel button (which you can hide):

```
class MainFrame(wx.Dialog):
    ...
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        # the frame must have a cancel button
        cancel_button = wx.Button(..., id=wx.ID_CANCEL)
        # it still works if you hide it
        cancel_button.Hide()
```

This seems to provide the default handling for the escape key.  You could even bind it to an event handler to perform some actions before closing - if you do the handler must use event.Skip(True) to propagate the event or event.Skip(False) to stop the cancel operation.

Comment: This is old, but just in case someone tries this. It doesn't appear to work for me when I use `cancel_button.Hide()`, but it does work if you replace that call with this one: `cancel_button.SetSize(wx.Size(0,0))`.

Comment: @TSeymour agreed, in modern wxpython this 0-sized button works, a hidden button does not (as it probably ignores events).